# How to get part of image in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to perform to operations:

1. Allow user see all available albums and pick a picture from one of them.
2. Select specific area of the picture of a specific size.

I do know how to pick an image using UIImagePicker, but i can't see all albums and can't crop specific area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `sourceType` on your UIImagePickerController to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` allows for selecting from all the images on the device (I don't remember if they will be divided by album or displayed in one huge list).

You can have UIImagePickerController provide a cropping interface by setting `allowsEditing`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to set scaling size programmaticly?